# Может ли союз быть общим элементом для частей ССП?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, ссп, сложное-предложение

Могут ли союзы быть общими элементами для двух простых предложений, соединённых союзами *и*, *да* (в значении *и*), *или*, *либо*?

Разделительный:

> *Либо инфляция снизится, **либо** она возрастёт[,] и начнётся кризис.*

Присоединительный:

> *Главное, курс должен быть практическим — с чёткими инструкциями для решения всех задач, с которыми ты будешь сталкиваться. **Также** в нём должно быть много практических заданий[,] и желательно, чтобы эти задания проверили и дали тебе обратную связь по тому, как ты их выполнил.*

Про противительный союз у Розенталя есть упоминание:

*Противительный союз, после которого или перед которым находятся два соединенных союзом и простых предложения, общим элементом не является, поэтому запятая перед и ставится: Ибрагим был бы очень рад избавиться, но ассамблея была дело должностное, и государь строго требовал присутствия своих приближённых (П.); Он подавил вздох и не спеша стал сворачивать папироску, но почему-то дрогнули руки, и он рассыпал на колени табак (Ш.); Гроза прошла, и тучи рассеялись, но духота ещё сохранялась* (http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=133).

Comment: Вам может быть полезна [эта ссылка](https://russkayarech.ru/ru/archive/2005-4/60-63).

Answer (score 2):

1. Судя по ответам на этом сайте, непротивительный союз может быть общим элементом.

**Либо инфляция снизится, либо она возрастёт и начнётся кризис.**

2. Не думаю, что *также* является общим элементом во втором предложении, так как второе предложение не самостоятельно по смыслу, в нем говорится об "этих заданиях", описанных в первом. Поэтому я бы запятую поставил.

**Также в нём должно быть много практических заданий, и желательно, чтобы эти задания проверили и дали тебе обратную связь по тому, как ты их выполнил.**

Примечание. Стилистику данного предложения ("дали обратную связь"; "связь по тому..."; то ли кто-то проверил задания и "дал свазь", то ли задания проверили кого-то и "дали связь") я не правил.

Comment: "...Второе предложение не самостоятельно по смыслу, в нем говорится об "этих заданиях", описанных в первом" — а как смысловая самостоятельность влияет на разделение запятой? Правило чёткое: есть общий элемент — запятая не ставится.

Comment: Дело в том, что он (элемент)  — не общий. А как это понять? По-моему, по смыслу, что я и пытался сделать.

Comment: Давайте я добавлю контекст, потому что, по мне, эти два предложения, соединённые союзом "и", присоединяются к предшествующему предложению с помощью союза "также" и он для них по смыслу является именно общим элементом.

Answer (score 2):

**Союз ЛИБО...ЛИБО**

Сравним два варианта:

(1) Либо инфляция снизится, либо она возрастёт и начнётся кризис.

(2) Либо инфляция снизится, либо она возрастёт, и (тогда) начнётся кризис.

Как мы видим, вариант (2) не имеет смысла: из него следует, что  кризис начнется в любом случае, а это не так.

**Союз ТАКЖЕ**

Также в нём **должно быть** много практических заданий, и **желательно**, чтобы эти задания проверили и сообщили тебе, как ты их выполнил.

Именно для этого предложения ТАКЖЕ не является общим элементом (сравнить: должно быть и желательно).

**У Розенталя** общим элементом может быть частица (*только,  вот* и др.), вводное слово (*по-видимому* и др.), а про союзы  (кроме противительных союзов) нет информации. Поэтому задачу относительно союзов, как я думаю, **надо решать самостоятельно,** в том числе с учетом интонации.

Comment: 1) Не понял вашей аргументации того, что также не является общим элементом. 2) Только противительный союз НО "не умеет"? Что насчёт союза А? "Я думаю, что подобная ситуация больше не повторится, а того сотрудника депремируют[,] и отдел будет работать эффективнее.

Comment: Вообще, у Розенталя примечание для всех противительных союзов: "Противительный союз, после которого или перед которым находятся два соединенных союзом и простых предложения, общим элементом не является, поэтому запятая перед и ставится".

Comment: Давайте я добавлю контекст, потому что, по мне, эти два предложения, соединённые союзом "и", присоединяются к предшествующему предложению с помощью союза "также" и он для них по смыслу является именно общим элементом.