# Запятые в предложении: «Но не спешите с выводами и вы сами всё поймете»

Tags: пунктуация, запятые

Подскажите, пожалуйста, ставятся ли запятые и, главное, почему в предложении: «Но не спешите с выводами и вы сами всё поймете».

Answer (score 1):

**Но не спешите с выводами, и вы сами всё поймёте.**

Сочинительный союз **и** соединяет простые предложения в составе сложного (ССП), поэтому [**по правилам**](http://videotutor-rusyaz.ru/uchenikam/teoriya/315-zapyatayaperedsyuzomi.html) перед ним ставится запятая.

1. *Но* ([вы] что сделайте?) *не спешите с выводами* — односоставное (без подлежащего, определенно-личное, побудительное).
2. *Вы* (что сделаете?) *сами всё поймёте* — двусоставное.

(В вашем предложении сказуемые не являются однородными.
Сравните: *Но **ты не спеши** с выводами **и не суди** сгоряча.* Запятая не нужна.)

P. S. Дополнение к дискуссии
Союз "но" определяется как <…> присоединительный,  если употребляется в начале реплики, которая является возражением собеседнику, или в речи одного лица при возражении самому себе ([Анализ определений союзов «а», «но»...](https://cyberleninka.ru/article/v/analiz-opredeleniy-soyuzov-a-no-and-but-i-ih-sinonimov-dannyh-v-sovremennyh-slovaryah)). Мне кажется, что это "наш" случай.

Answer (score 0):

Корректно:
**Но не спешите с выводами, и вы сами всё поймете.**

Это сложносочиненное предложение (ССП), состоящее из двух простых: побудительного "но не спешите с выводами" и повествовательного "вы сами всё поймете". В ССП ставится запятая перед союзом *и*.

Примечание. Противительный союз *но* общим элементом не является. См. у Розенталя ([§ 30. Запятая в сложносочиненном предложении](http://old-rozental.ru/punctum_uk.php?pid=228)):

> 2. Противительный союз, после которого или перед которым находятся два соединенных союзом и простых предложения, общим элементом не является, поэтому запятая перед и ставится: Ибрагим был бы очень рад избавиться, **но** ассамблея была дело должностное, и государь строго требовал присутствия своих приближённых (П.); Он подавил вздох и не спеша стал сворачивать папироску, **но** почему-то дрогнули руки, и он рассыпал на колени табак (Ш.); Гроза прошла, и тучи рассеялись, но духота ещё сохранялась.

Comment: Скажите, пожалуйста, а у наших классиков есть указание на то, что присоединительные союзы, в том числе союз НО, не являются общими элементами. Особенно по поводу союза НО не очень ясно.

Comment: @Sharon Я дополнил ответ.

Comment: Да, спасибо, но в этих примерах НО не является присоединительным союзом, а меня  интересует тема именно присоединительных союзов в качестве общих элементов. У нас есть какие-нибудь указание на это, может, хотя бы в в Грамоте.ру?

Comment: @Sharon А где сказано, что "но" может быть присоединительным союзом?

Comment: У Розенталя  http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=140#pp140  5. Постановка запятой между присоединительным союзом (в начале предложения, после точки) и следующим за ним подчинительным союзом зависит от значения союза:

Comment: @Sharon У Лопатина ([Знаки препинания в сложносочиненном предложении](http://orthographia.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=133#pp133)) перечислены, как я понимаю, *все* случаи, когда запятая не ставится, и союзы там отсутствуют вообще.  Да и Розенталя я понимаю в том же духе.

Comment: @Sharon Множество примеров в Нацкорпусе, вот один из них:  Но уроки общения с искателями чувственных удовольствий впрок не шли, и Элла продолжала свои опыты. [Сергей Любимов. Призрак убитой ошибся адресом (2003) // «Богатей» (Саратов), 2003.06.05]

Comment: Это да, но вопросы возникают, и "вопрошающие"  хотят, чтобы ответ подтверждали ссылкой, которой нет. Например: https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/441553/Может-ли-союз-быть-общим-элементом-для-частей-ССП

Comment: @Sharon О да, о таких союзах как либо..либо я не подумал. Наверно, нужно как-то оговориться, мол если это влияет на понимание  смысла, то запятая не ставится.

Comment: Не думаю, что это надо сделать, союз либо....либо обычный повторяющийся союз. В той теме речь шла о присоединительном союзе ТАКЖЕ.

Comment: @Sharon Мы далеко зашли. В ответе на данный вопрос, по-моему, не надо искать трудных путей — там запятая.

Comment: В запятой я не сомневаюсь, мне хочется найти этому официальное подтверждение. Если встретится такая информация, то поделитесь ею с обществом.

Comment: Союз "но" определяется как <…> присоединительный, в сочетании со словами, обозначающими время; присоединительный (употребляется в начале реплики, которая является возражением собеседнику, или в речи одного лица при возражении самому себе) https://cyberleninka.ru/article/v/analiz-opredeleniy-soyuzov-a-no-and-but-i-ih-sinonimov-dannyh-v-sovremennyh-slovaryah [стр. 30] Возможно, именно это имелось в виду?