# К тому же на реке много порогов(,) и бурный поток подмывает снизу лед

Tags: пунктуация

Хотел бы узнать, является ли союз *к тому же* общим членом предложения, и, следовательно, запятую ставить не требуется.

**К тому же на реке много порогов(,) и бурный поток подмывает снизу лед.**

На грамоте в справочнике есть такое (в примерах пунктуационного оформления предложений, содержащих союз *к тому же*):

**К тому же каждый день шел снег, и каждое утро приходилось**

В данном примере запятая перед *и* поставлена, следовательно *к тому же* не выступает в качестве общего члена предложения.

Если это так, то, прошу вас, приведите соответствующее правило!

Заранее благодарю!

Comment: https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/441553

Answer (score 3):

Если предложение задумывается как:
*К тому же на реке много порогов, и к тому же бурный поток подмывает снизу лед.*
и паузы нет, то можно было бы и не ставить запятую.

**Но!**
Здесь бурный поток является **следствием** наличия большого количества порогов — нет однородности (возможности поменять элементы местами), поэтому в книге и стоит запятая.

Розенталь:
*Как только сапёры перетащили машину на другую сторону и поставили на шоссе, Зубенко дал газ, и грузовик преспокойно поехал дальше* (Медведев) — последнее предложение указывает на общее **следствие**.
http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=133

*К тому же каждый день шел снег, и каждое утро приходилось, прежде чем приступить к самой работе, порядочно поработать лопатой.* || Здесь чётко выражено следствие, поэтому и стоит запятая. Смысл такой:
*К тому же есть такая проблема, и из-за этого приходилось вот так её устранять.*

Comment: Поддерживаю ответ, хотя здесь просто следствие, а не общее следствие. Оставлю в комментарии ссылку на [эту статью](https://russkayarech.ru/ru/archive/2005-4/60-63) в журнале "Русская речь" (см. п.3 в конце статьи).

Comment: У Розенталя общее, скорее всего, потому что до этого 2 простых предложения, а не 1. Но это сосем не принципиально. Самым спорным моментам он уделял почему-то мало внимания, обычно лишь по одному примеру, а самым простым — больше всего. Печально, что союзы как потенциальный общий элемент никто не рассматривает. Самые спорные случаи — когда значение следствия и соединительная "сила" общего элемента примерно равны ([например](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/457430)). И конечно же, это никто не рассматривает.

Comment: Здравствуйте, oleedd, приятно видеть вас на форуме! Мне понятен ваш ответ. В грамматике указано, что только при однородном сочинении  простые предложения в ССП могут иметь общий элемент (нет однородности – нет и общего элемента), это показатель однородности  Кустова, стр.221-222 https://www.rsuh.ru/upload/main/media/от%20преподавателей/sintaksis-sovremennogo-russkogo-jazyka_kustova-g_i_-i-dr_2005-256s.pdf

Comment: Но к вам такой интересный вопрос: это сочинение (ССП) или бессоюзная связь (БСП)? «К тому же» – это всего лишь союзный аналог (как, к примеру наречие «поэтому» в БСП), а не грамматический союз, его нет в перечне сочинительных союзов. В Грамматике -80 «к тому же» относится к группе слов, которые выступают как аналоги союзов § 1673. rusgram.narod.ru/1669-1688.html  А здесь нужна запятая? Было уже поздно, к тому же пошел дождь и поднялся ветер. Если нет, то "к тому же" может быть общим элементом при однородном сочинении.

Comment: На Грамоте "к тому же" — союз, тогда сочинение. Просто не силён в классификациях (это лишь теория, они часто бесполезны на практике), тем более сочетаний слов как частей речи. Тут была масса самых спорных вопросов, которые затрагивают чуть ли не все самые уязвимые места правил (почти о всех уже знал, так как сам интересовался), поэтому не удерживался от ответов. Но они уже закончились и всё стало как прежде. Кроме того, в предыдущем предложении такая же структура (в том числе смысловая), как и в примере одного вашего вопроса. Тот вопрос очень крутой, и раз вы уже на месте, то смогу ответить.

Comment: "3) наличие в второй предикативной части наречий и части значение следствия, уступки, ограничения, возмещения, которых конкретизируют частное синтаксическое значение и подчеркиваю неравноправие это части" — в этой книге жутко не хватает примеров (в чём преимущество Розенталя, у него гораздо больше текста примеров, чем правил, а примеры (которые часто удивляют) лучше всё объясняют, чем сами правила). Очень хотелось бы увидеть примеры (желательно с потенциальным общим элементом) уступки, ограничения и возмещения, так как имел дело только с общим элементом при следствии.

Comment: Теория – это не такая уж плохая вещь. Вот вы говорили о неоднородности предложений, а где окончательный вывод? Надо же связать неоднородность и общий элемент. У Кустовой они связаны – вот и доказательство,  а без этого  просто мнение. На  Грамоте  «к тому же» – союз, но это упрощенный подход.  Об этом  Грамматика-80 говорит, также  у Кустовой присоединительные отношения только в СПП и  БСП (но даже в СПП такого союза нет) .  Скорее всего, это БСП, а там запятая ставится в любом случае .  Получается, что « к тому же» как бы условный союз.  Кстати, в моем предложении  запятую будете  ставить?

Comment: Вот Серж нам говорит, что союз не может быть общим элементом, а это и не союз вовсе, а союзный  аналог. Это союзы И, НО, А, ДА не могут, а «к тому же» очень даже может. Вот вам и ответ Сержу,  причем на уровне теоретической  грамматики.  Так что теория – полезная вещь, надо этим пользоваться. Что касается форума, то это от людей зависит.  Сейчас грамматику, стилистику, пунктуацию как бы отодвинули в сторону, а именно там нужны настоящие знания, а не философия. Но все можно изменить при желании.  Так что не пропадайте,  найдем интересные темы.

Comment: "Теория – это не такая уж плохая вещь" — конечно, но не всегда она нужна на практике (разные сложные термины и классификации). А вывод в том, что есть два варианта (в одну фразу оно тоже читается). Всё зависит от логического ударения на слове "порогов" (а ведь когда-то вы меня "познакомили" с ними, в своих ответах, универсальная вещь, швейцарский нож для спорных случаев). Нужно смотреть, что сильнее: следствие либо влияние общего элемента. А где запятую? Перед "и поднялся"? Конечно, нет. Не думаю, что дождь вызывает ветер. "найдем интересные темы" — не думаю, что их много осталось.

Comment: Мне кажется, что "к тому же" нормально рассматривать как союз — присоединяем к тому же (к ранее сказанному) следующее. Самое сложное — максимальное соответствие переводов оригиналу так, чтобы оно звучало. Этим сейчас приходится заниматься.

Comment: "Это союзы И, НО, А, ДА не могут" — стоп, чего это? Об этом же нигде не сказано. НО точно может, хоть и крайне-крайне редко, при всём уважении к Розенталю. Ответ дам на ваш вопрос по этой теме. Насчёт остальных союзов не уверен, но и не разбирался. Ещё могу сказать, что Розенталь уклонялся от самых сложных тем, там он говорил, что обычно делают вот так. Связано это с тем, что он не выдумывал правила, а выводил их по примерам из классики или брал откуда-то. По самым сложным темам информации и примеров мало либо они и вовсе отсутствуют. В связи с этим отсутствие разрешения не означает запрет.

Comment: Нет, так нельзя. Нужно однозначно доказать, могут или не могут (про союзы  И, НО, А, ДА ). Попробуйте... Вот вам интересная тема (как  теорема в  математике), развивает мышление.

Comment: Дело в том, что это одна из самых сложных проблем в принципе. Такое больше к РАН. Может, затрону и другие союзы (помимо НО) в ответе на ваш вопрос. Но коротко говоря, противительные на это способны, а с соединительными это звучит не по-русски (из-за повторения И либо ДА), так не говорят. Кстати, логическое ударение гораздо больше помогает разобраться (по крайней мере мне) в случае с общим элементом, чем размышления о следствии и однородности.

Comment: И ещё. В языке, к сожалению, не получится доказывать так, как в математике. Здесь всё больше сводится к тому, говорят ли так люди или нет или похоже ли оно хоть чем-то на то, что употребляется, а также к придумыванию примеров, благодаря которым какие-либо утверждения становятся более очевидными. Особенно это касается проблемы с однородными элементами. Чем выше однородность, тем больше влияние однородного элемента. А при союзах однородность должна быть абсолютной, что предусматривает возможность поменять элементы местами. Это по крайней мере (как минимум) даёт шанс.

Comment: Ну что я могу вам сказать. Решать задачу можно любым способом, но потом  решение нужно доказывать (правила  Розенталя, ПАС  и  грамматика).  А иначе это не ответ, а мнение.  Текстовые примеры важны, но опять же для решения. Если они противоречат правилам, то это будет авторская пунктуация (хотя она может быть  более современной).  Однородные отношения в грамматике определяются строго.  Вот что сказано про противительные союзы. Предложения однородного состава – только сопоставительные с союзом А (он художник, а она студентка), все остальные – неоднородные. Ну да ладно, потом  еще поговорим.

Answer (score 0):

Союз не является второстепенным членом, и вообще не является членом предложения, поэтому запятая нужна.

Общим может быть не только член предложения, но и сравнительный оборот, вводное слово, придаточная часть сложноподчиненного предложения.

См. [Справочное пособие по русскому языку Д. Э. Розенталя](http://old-rozental.ru/)

Comment: https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/441553

Comment: @oleedd, я видел и вопрос, и ответ. И? Что вы хотели сказать этой ссылкой?

Comment: Что нет запрета на соединение частей ССП союзом как общим элементом.

Comment: Где это написано? По той ссылке, которую вы привели?

Comment: Как бы да......

Comment: Примеры и доказательства прошу. По ссылке представлено субъективное мнение,предположение автора.

Comment: По ссылке не указано, что есть общий запрет на этот счёт. Если у вас есть источник с запретом, то было бы очень интересно взглянуть. А пока здесь действует принцип "разрешено всё, что не запрещено".

Comment: Союз не является таким семантическим или структурным компонентом, который может относится ко всему предложению.

Comment: Это довольно спорно, интонационно такое соединение вполне звучит, если замысел такой: *ab + ac = a(b + c)* — чтобы не повторять союз. То есть с точки зрения практики — применимо.

Comment: При чем тут математика? Зачем математику приплетат? Звучит не звучит.

Comment: Да это не математика, а просто чтобы показать, что хотелось союз 2 раза употребить.

Answer (score 0):

Думаю, запятая нужна: логично, если к "общему элементу" (к тому же *К тому же*) относятся независимые друг от друга идеи, а здесь второе предложение логически вытекает из первого: **из-за того**, что на реке много порогов, образуется бурный поток, подмывающий лёд снизу.