# Запятая между однородными придаточными?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, тире

> — Уж они умели дожать эту грань, голландские художники — как спелость переходит в гниль. Фрукт идеален, но это ненадолго, он вот-вот испортится. Особенно здесь, видишь, — сказала она, протянув руку у меня из-за плеча, чтобы прочертить форму в воздухе, — вот этот переход — бабочка. — **Подкрылье было таким пыльцеватым, хрупким, что, казалось, коснись она его(?) и цвет смажется.** — Как красиво он это сыграл. Покой с дрожью движения.
> [Донна Тартт. Щегол](https://books.google.ee/books?id=fUKfBQAAQBAJ&pg=PT29&lpg=PT29&dq=%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BA%D1%80%D1%8B%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B5%20%D0%B1%D1%8B%D0%BB%D0%BE%20%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%BC%20%D0%BF%D1%8B%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%86%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8B%D0%BC,%20%D1%85%D1%80%D1%83%D0%BF%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%BC,%20%D1%87%D1%82%D0%BE&source=bl&ots=HvfZwLYROM&sig=ACfU3U2MtpWbHby7AX61j7C2NS-Iq_RfWw&hl=ru&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiamcGWxJb1AhUBt4sKHYxwAqcQ6AF6BAgdEAM#v=onepage&q=%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BA%D1%80%D1%8B%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B5%20%D0%B1%D1%8B%D0%BB%D0%BE%20%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%BC%20%D0%BF%D1%8B%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%86%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8B%D0%BC%2C%20%D1%85%D1%80%D1%83%D0%BF%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%BC%2C%20%D1%87%D1%82%D0%BE&f=false)

Почему не ставится запятая (тире) перед союзом И? "Казалось" — общее вводное?

Comment: Да, желательно что-то поставить, там ведь следствие. В одну фразу (без знака) оно не читается.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Правильно:  *Подкрылье было таким пыльцеватым, хрупким, что, **казалось, коснись она его – и цвет смажется.***

Пояснение

1. Это синонимический вариант такого предложения: *Подкрылье было таким пыльцеватым, хрупким, **что, казалось, если коснется она его, то цвет смажется.***

В данном предложении повелительная форма «коснись» используется для образования **условного наклонения**, а вводное слово «казалось» обозначает **нереальное условие** (предположительность действия).

**2. Грамматическая справка**

В грамматике эта тема рассматривается в разделе  «Непрямые употребления повелительного наклонения»

[http://rusgram.ru/Императив#48](http://rusgram.ru/%D0%98%D0%BC%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B2#48)  **Императив побудительного условия:**  Поставь эти вазы на подоконник – увидишь, как весело заиграют в них лучи весеннего солнышка… [«Даша» (2004)]. Читайте – и обрящете истину, скрытую между газетных строк. [«Финансовая Россия» (2002)]

**Императив условия** – наиболее частотное из непрямых употреблений императива. Как правило, такой императив обозначает **контрфактивное условие**, то есть описывает ситуацию, которая никогда не имела и не будет иметь место.

Пример: *Он вёз жену из родильного отделения районной больницы, она держала на руках ребёнка, и ему казалось, что **проживи он тысячу лет – он не забудет этого дня.*** [В. Гроссман]

**3. О знаках препинания**

У Розенталя вводное слово может являться общим элементов в ССП, но возможны **исключения** (например, вводное слово относится только к первому предложению и т.д.) http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=133#pp133  Пункт 4.

Данный случай также можно считать исключительным в связи **с нестандартной грамматикой предложения.** Здесь вводное слово «казалось,  форма повелительного наклонения «коснись»  и союз И **совместно участвуют** в образовании грамматической формы, которая выражает  **нереальное условие.**

**Разделительное тире** в таких предложениях ставится, как правило.

Answer (score 0):

Да, тут общее вводное у двух предложений с сложносочиненной связью, и поэтому запятая не ставится. [Вот ссылка, пункт 4](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=133#pp133)

Также есть правило, что тире ставится при сложносочиненной связи при контрастах — неожиданная смена событий, резкая и значительная смена событий, эмоциональное потрясение или улучшение и т.д, но если контраст интонационно не подчеркивается, то ставится запятая. [Ссылка на Розенталя](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=135#pp135)

В итоге: если контраст интонационно подчеркивается, то ставится тире, а если контраст интонационно не подчеркивается, то не ставится ничего.

Вот пара примеров из Нац. корпуса с тире:

> Казалось, еще круг ― и все кончено. [Б. Е. Клетинич. Моё частное бессмертие (2015) // «Волга», 2016]
> Казалось, шагну в темноту ― и все, конец, растерзают… [Дмитрий Емец. Таня Гроттер и колодец Посейдона (2004)]
> И, когда генерал и Мария входили в столовую, слуга как раз вносил поднос, а рядом шагал старенький повар Александер в высоком белом колпаке, накрахмаленном так, что, казалось, возьми его в руки ― и колпак переломится. [Вацлав Михальский. Одинокому везде пустыня (2003)]

Comment: То не контраст, а следствие.

Comment: Это и контраст, и следствие. То, что цвет смазывает, является в данном контексте чем-то неожиданным и удивляющим. Но при отношениях следствия между сложносочиненными нет каких-то особых интонационных и, следовательно, пунктуационных отношений — нет тире при следствии при сложносочиненной связи.

Comment: При следствии есть логическое ударение, в связи с чем требуется какой-то знак, не обязательно тире. Но чем чётче и сильнее следствие, тем тире актуальнее.

Comment: Но есть союз ‟и”, и примеров сложносочиненных предложений, где есть следствие, но нет тире, бескрайнее колличество.

Comment: И что, запятой тоже нет? Говорю же, что необязательно тире.

Comment: Я вообще практически не видел тире между сложносочиненными с отношениями следствия, хотя видел тысячи примеров обратного.

Comment: Вот предложение из справочника Розенталя сходу: ‟Вскоре после восхода набежала туча и брызнул короткий дождь (П.)” Вот еще: ‟Ибрагим был бы очень рад избавиться, но ассамблея была дело должностное, и государь строго требовал присутствия своих приближённых (П.)” Еще: ‟Уже совсем рассвело и народ стал подниматься, когда я вернулся в свою комнату (Л. Т.)” Еще: ‟Через час явилась возможность ехать: метель утихла, небо прояснилось, и мы отправились (П.)”

Comment: Это сложная тема, здесь связь с общим элементом сильнее, чем следственность (которая не показывается). То есть произошло одно и дальше другое, а не одно, из-за чего другое. Жаль, что вы не понимаете, как это всё читается. Советую разобраться. Читал недавно этот пример и даже не заметил, что там есть следствие. Вывод: оно там не важно.

Comment: То есть дождь начался не потому, что набежала туча, а это просто несвязанные последовательные события?

Comment: Не всегда нужно показывать это пунктуационно. Важную роль играет то, разное ли время у глаголов. Советую разобраться с тем, как оно читается! Иначе вы не сможете понять это всё.

Comment: Вы уже второй человек за сегодня на форуме, который рассказывает о том, что надо познать глубинный пунктуационный эфир. Когда ставишь кого-то в тупик на форуме по пунктуации, то эти люди начинают рассказывать, что ты не познал глубинный пунктуационный эфир.

Comment: Лишь читая правила и примеры, вы не сможете полностью разобраться с такого рода вещами.

Comment: Это может помочь: https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/466949

Comment: Если хотите показать, что второе происходит из-за первого, то ставьте знак, а если нет — то не ставьте. Но в каждом случае есть лучшее решение, вы можете выбрать худшее.

Comment: @oleedd  "Запятая между однородными придаточными".   Так называется вопрос. А вы видите здесь однородные придаточные? Никто из отвечающих о них и слова не сказал. Надо все-таки внимательно читать заголовок – ведь именно так определяет предложение автор. А если представить, что они там были бы, может ли там находиться вводное слово?

Comment: @Sharon Ну да, а они не однородные. *А если представить, что они там были бы* — а это как?

Answer (score 0):

> Подкрылье было таким пыльцеватым, хрупким, что, казалось, коснись она
> его(?) и цвет смажется.

На мой взгляд, более удачной была бы такая пунктуация:

***Подкрылье было таким пыльцеватым, хрупким, что казалось: коснись она его – и цвет смажется.***

(Запятая перед *казалось* здесь не нужна.)

Ср. с примерами из Нацкорпуса:

*Зеленый свет опускался временами так низко, **что казалось: кинь шапку ― и закачается занавес.*** [Василий Песков. Белые сны (1964)]

*Температура воздуха даже в тени доходила до пятидесяти градусов, а на солнце песок был так горяч, **что казалось: поставь на него чайник ― и он закипит.*** [В. Белецкая. Старый добрый лен // «Огонек», 1961]

Comment: А звучит ли здесь двоеточие? Вообще не звучит. Рассматриваете ли вы вообще звучание? Его в первую очередь надо учитывать. Чтобы более-менее звучало, надо как-то так: *Подкрылье было таким пыльцеватым, хрупким, что казалось: она его коснётся – и цвет смажется.* Для двоеточия нужна самостоятельность, а "коснись она его" сопоставимо с подчинённым условием "если она коснётся".

Comment: Вы отказываете людям в праве по-разному произносить это предложение (тире), так еще потом отказываете им в праве по-разному конструировать это предложение (посмотрите последний пример в моем ответе).

Comment: У меня в ответе тоже есть пример из Нац. корпуса. Ваши примеры только доказывают, что можно и так и сяк писать.

Comment: @slava1947 Совет: рассматривайте звучание (как оно читается), не только примеры и правила.

Comment: _oleedd: @slava1947 Совет: рассматривайте звучание (как оно читается), не только примеры и правила._ ===  Сказать по правде, я именно этим обычно и руководствуюсь! Но… При наличии тире после «его» (а этот знак я считаю наиболее предпочтительным в данном случае) двоеточие после «казалось», на мой взгляд, наиболее чётко отделяет ту часть предложения, в которой рассказывается о том, что именно «казалось». Кстати, свой вариант пунктуационного оформления этого предложения Вы, по-моему, пока ещё не привели…

Comment: Я просто добавил бы тире. Чётко отделяет как? Графически? Нет такого принципа в пунктуации. С длительной паузой там плохо звучит. С двоеточием звучит совсем иначе, нежели с запятой. Двоеточие кстати, если дальше что-то серьёзное и длинное.